# Concatenate strings and numbers

Tags: c++, concatenation

I have a function which takes a `const char*` argument. I need to concatenate two string literals and an `int` to pass to this argument. Basically this is what I'm trying to do:

```
open(const char* filename) {}

void loadFile(int fileID)
{
    open("file" + fileID + ".xml");
}

int main()
{
    loadFile(1);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make this work as simply as possible? I tried changing the loadFile function to take a `const char*` and then doing `open(std::string("file").c_str() + fileID + std::string(".xml").c_str());` but then I get `error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'` so I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Simply as possible you ask? Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Use `std::to_string` on the `int` and then `c_str` at the end.

Comment: @chris You cannot create a `string` from an `int` without using a stream, formatter or something like that... Direct creation will fail and concatenation will interpret the `int` as a `char`.

Comment: @Johan, `std::to_string` converts it to a string.

Comment: @chris: I believe that is a C++11 function.

Comment: @JeremiahWillcock, Indeed it is, but the OP hasn't disallowed it.

Comment: @chris: sorry, I did read `std::string` instead of `std::to_string`. Thanks for the tip, I did not know this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11, you can use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to get a string representation of a number:

```
std::string filename = "file" + std::to_string(fileId) + ".xml";
```

However, if you have Boost available, I think using Boost format, as discussed in Johan's answer, is more readable.

Comment: Chosen because I can keep everything within the function call, `open(std::string("file" + std::to_string(fileID) + ".xml").c_str());` which is exactly my goal.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use something like:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "file" << fileID << ".xml";
open(os.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `stringstream` as stated before or [Boost format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#examples):

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

void loadFile(int fileID)
{
  std::string filename = (boost::format("File%d.xml") % fileID).str();
  open(filename.c_str();
}
```

Comment: Would be more complete with a relevant include and fully qualified access of the `format` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use to_string()

```
open("file" + to_string(fileID) + ".xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a superset of c.  You could use sprintf:

```
void loadFile(unsigned int fileID)
{
   const int BUFFER_SIZE = 128;
   char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   sprintf(buffer,"file%u.xml");
   open(buffer);
}
```

This is portable, should be safe for all passed in (uint) values, etc.

You can also use snprintf(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,....) if you are concerned about overrunning the buffer.